# Get executed SQL statement from pgPromise query result

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm writing an API that does queries over multiple postgres databases using node and [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

I'm interested in getting the executed SQL statement from query result. Something like [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) outputs to console. I've set up pg-monitor and noticed there is a `setLog` method which I can use to get the data I need, but it would be perfect if I could get the same data from the place I'm executing the query from.

Point of this would be to enable the API to return both the query results and the metadata like the executed SQL. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it would be perfect if I could get the same data from the place I'm executing the query from.

In this case you can [format](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html#.format) the query yourself, log it and then pass it into  the query method:

```
const query = pgp.as.format('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $1', 123);
console.log('QUERY:', query);
db.any(query).then().catch()
```

All query methods use this formatting function underneath.

Note the difference however. When there is an issue with the query formatting, any query method reports it within its `catch` section, while use of `as.format` function directly will throw an error, if there is an issue, because formatting is synchronous.

**UPDATE**

With [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) version 8.2.0 and later you can even do the following:

```
const query = values => {
    const q = pgp.as.format('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $1', values);
    console.log('QUERY:', q);
    return q;
};
db.any(query, values).then().catch()
```

It is safer this way, as any error related to query formatting will be handled by the query method.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! I'm actually using QueryFiles to separate SQL from JS, so I can get the SQL from `query` property on QueryFile object.

Comment: @IvanKović No, you should not! You should pass `QueryFile` object directly into `format`.

Comment: thanks for catching that! That was a quick and wrong idea :)